# Bulk Insert Load Failed in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, csv, bulkinsert

I'm trying to insert a `.csv` file into an existing table. The existing table has 3 columns and these are IDs (just being assigned in the table), Student Number, and Group Number.

In my `.csv`, I have the format below, but every time I insert it, I get an error

> The bulk load failed. Unexpected NULL value in data file row, column 1. The destination column (ID) is defined as NOT Null.

So how do I ignore the first column?

This is the `.CSV` file:

```
   ID,StudentNumber,GroupNumber
   ,0000123456,3
   ,0000794613,3
```

The SQL that I'm using

```
    BULK INSERT [dbo].[Table_StudentNumber]
    FROM 'E:\CSV\sample.csv'
    WITH
    (
        FIRSTROW = 2,
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
        ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
    );
```

Comment: Look into using a format file with this. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178129.aspx

Comment: Hi. Are you referring to the bcp?

Comment: You can use a format file with `BULK INSERT` too.

Comment: Bulk insert into a temp table and then only select the columns you want into your actual table

Answer (score 3):

Don't bulk insert your CSV into the real table. Insert it first in a table without the identity column, alter the data and then insert it into the real table.

Comment: Hi. Are you referring to the ID column in the table? Pretty much the ID will be based on the next number available in the table.